# When watching a tag, to which email address do you send the notification?

Tags: support, status-completed, stack-overflow-for-teams

In Stack Overflow for Teams, do you send the notification to the company email address, or the private email address?

Answer (score 3):

It's the email address that is configured for you in the team - so it will be the company email address if that what you used to join the Team. You can see what that is by visiting your [email settings](https://stackoverflow.com/users/email/settings/current) and scrolling down to the section with the name of your team.